# Problemas com vários formulários ajax na mesma página

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Estou tendo um problema estranho quando coloco vários formulários em uma mesma página (no caso na index) todos possuem o parâmetro `remote: true` criados a partir de um loop em meus registros. O problema é que somente o primeiro formulário funciona com o ajax, o segundo envia um requeste normal e é direcionado para o show.

Abaixo meu index que é onde são gerados meu formulários:

```
  <% @mensagens.each do |mensagem| %>
  <%= form_for(mensagem, remote: true,:authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="widget">        
        <!-- BLOCK -->

          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="innerAll half">
                  <div class='col-md-10'><%= f.number_field :avaliacao %></div>
                  <div class='col-md-2'><%= mensagem.slug %></div>
                </div>                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="innerAll half">
                  <%= f.text_area :texto, :class=>"col-md-12 form-control", :placeholder=>"Mensagem" %>
                </div>                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="innerAll half ">
                  <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.check_box :aprovado %></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.check_box :status %></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 btn"><%= f.text_field :autor,:class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Autor" %></div> 
                  <div class="col-md-2"><%= f.submit "Salvar", :class=>"btn btn-success" %></div>
                </div>                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row innerAll half border-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class='notyfy_wrapper mensagem_<%= mensagem.id %>'>
                <div class="notyfy_message">
                  <span class="notyfy_text">
                    <div id="alerta"></div>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          

      </div>
      <!-- BLOCK -->
    </div>



  </div>

  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Coloquei a página no ar para vocês poderem dar uma olhada: http://droido.com.br/mensagens

Comment: Não utilize links de páginas que possam ficar offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando sua página percebo que o erro não está exatamente no *remote* mas sim em seu formulário pois um esta contido dentro do outro.

Por exemplo:

```
<form>
   <form>

   </form>
</form>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso Luiz! na verdade estava faltando um div então o navegador interpretava erroneamente e colocava um form dentro do outro. Obrigado, colocarei o html gerado em um outro serviço para posteriores consultas.